# display calender in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code is working well in input box.it is not working in a tag
I want to get the same action in a tag 'sample'
I attached my code.

```
<div id="datepickerContainer">
</div>
<input id="datepicker" type="text">

<script src="/external/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true
 });
  $('#datepickerContainer').on('click',function() { $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('show'); });

   // Hover states on the static widgets
   $( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
   function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
   },
    function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Post your html and create a fiddle please

Comment: I dont know how to create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below html nd JavaScript code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/css/datePicker.css" />
        <script src="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/js/jquery.datePicker-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <title>Content Delv Logs</title>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).ready(function() {
                $('#date-pick').datePicker({clickInput: true});
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date-pick" value=""/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of <input type="text" name="date" id="date-pick" value=""/> I want it in <a>sample</a>

Comment: Add this line to get date in a input box.

Comment: save above code as html file and try you will get your answer :-)